# Facebook SDK in Unity Not Letting Unity Generate Size Logs

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I came through a strange Issue: Facebook sdk in unity is not letting unity generate size logs in the editor settings after build(Android) and even Build Report Tool is not working, but when i deleted it, i am getting size logs in Editor Logs and Build Report Tool Also Working, is there any solution to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is debug android key has not found.

You should install openssl.

and set environment variable in Windows 10 operating system.

Example - System variable -> Path -> modify -> add C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin